# How can I make empty spaces?

Tags: dokuwiki

How I can make empty spaces in wiki because I tried

```
''      '', 
<br> </br>,
## text( for Ordered a list)
```

and this things doesn't  work.
Anyone have an idea,  way ?

Comment: You should try with &nbsp.

Comment: I try, but don't work

Comment: it's a difference between wiki and dokuwiki ?

Comment: May this plugin link helpful to you :- https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:space

Comment: sorry but where I supposed to put this plug ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Admin page** and then go to **Confuguration settings**.

Then go to the **Editing Section.**

Set **Allow embedded HTML** to true.

Now you can make empty spaces with:

```
<HTML>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
</HTML>
```

When you want the emty space to be bigger, insert more `<br>`